# How to write type annotations for a Python function that takes a variable number of arguments in a stub file?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I would like to write type hints in a stub file for the following function:

```py
#foo.py
def foo(*args, bar="bar"): ...
```

My requirements are the following:

1. If there are no `args` given, the return type is `any`.
2. If there is one `args` of type `_P` given, the return type is `_P`.
3. If there are multiple `args` given, they must be of the same type `_P` and the return type is `tuple[_P, ...]`.

I tried the following:

```py
# foo.pyi
@overload
def foo(bar: str = ...) -> Any: ...
@overload
def foo(args: _P, bar: str = ...) -> _P: ...
@overload
def foo(arg1: _P, *args: _P, bar: str = ...) -> tuple[_P, ...]: ...
```

But running `python -m mypy.stubtest foo` gives me the error `stub argument "bar" is not keyword-only`, and making the argument keyword-only by adding `*args` in front masks the overloads below.

I also tried `foo(*, bar: str = ...)`, but that does not seem to mark `bar` as keyword only. Adding the `*` changes the error message from

```
error: foo.foo is inconsistent, stub argument "bar" is not keyword-only
Stub: in file /home/niklas/Desktop/test/foo.pyi:5
Overload(def (bar: builtins.str =) -> Any, def [_P] (args: _P`-1, bar: builtins.str =) -> _P`-1, def [_P] (arg1: _P`-1, *args: _P`-1, bar: builtins.str =) -> builtins.tuple[_P`-1, ...])
Inferred signature: def (arg1: _P`-1 = ..., bar: builtins.str = ..., *args)
Runtime: in file /home/niklas/Desktop/test/foo.py:1
def (*args, bar='bar')
```

to (note the star `*` in the third line):

```
error: foo.foo is inconsistent, stub argument "bar" is not keyword-only
Stub: in file /home/niklas/Desktop/test/foo.pyi:5
Overload(def (*, bar: builtins.str =) -> Any, def [_P] (args: _P`-1, bar: builtins.str =) -> _P`-1, def [_P] (arg1: _P`-1, *args: _P`-1, bar: builtins.str =) -> builtins.tuple[_P`-1, ...])
Inferred signature: def (arg1: _P`-1 = ..., bar: builtins.str = ..., *args)
Runtime: in file /home/niklas/Desktop/test/foo.py:1
def (*args, bar='bar')
```

Comment: Try `foo(*, bar: str = ...)`. Putting an `*` marks the next arguments as keyword only.

Comment: @undefined Please post that as an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work for me. I'll update the question.

Comment: @InSync this is not an answer since I did not test that nor did I correctly answer the problem.

Comment: Is [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&flags=strict&gist=72178abd8b1374be9f276b46f8ee5f15) what you're looking for? Also, consider employing PEP 646 if the size of the tuple returned equals the number of arguments of type `_P`.

Comment: You need to add `*` after `args` in the second example as well, to make sure `bar` is keyword-only in all three overloads.

Comment: I think you made a mistake and posted the same error message twice. Can you fix the question please?

Comment: @jtb I adjusted the question to point out the subtle difference.

Answer (score 0):

A solution was given by @undefined and @chepner in the comments. Note the star `*` in the first and second signature:

```py
# foo.pyi
@overload
def foo(*, bar: str = ...) -> Any: ...
@overload
def foo(args: _P, *, bar: str = ...) -> _P: ...
@overload
def foo(arg1: _P, *args: _P, bar: str = ...) -> tuple[_P, ...]: ...
```